# upload a photo from the albums in facebook login user account

Tags: android

Hi I want to upload a photo from facebook albumns into my application .
I got result from belo link
[Browsing facebook album](http://java.dzone.com/articles/browsing-facebook-albums.)

But I want to display the log in user albums,Can u suggest me.Thanks in advance